# motherboard with three or four sata3 ports , socket compatible with cheap processor (for a diy NAS)

Tags: motherboard, processor, compatibility

I have decided to mount my own nas in a relatively cheap way. 
I found a motherboard with enough sata3 ports for my needs (ASRock A320M-DGS) and a cheap processor (AMD A4-4000). The only issue is that the motherboard has a AM4 socket while the processor has been designed for a FM2 socket.

[edited]

Since it appears that these elements are not compatible, could someone give me good alternatives (combination of motherboard and processor) within the same range of price and that fit my purpose (nas for my personal use, motherboard with 3 or 4 sata ports)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, this combination will not work.